# Combining images with CUDA

Tags: image-processing, performance-tuning, cudalink, gpu

**SMALL UPDATE**: This question is left as unanswered, because none of the existing answers as of yet actually use CUDA (though, whilst being very useful).

**2nd Edition**:
To make it a bit more clear, and to summarize the discussion in comments.

**I have a small image**, like this one:

```
InsertImage = 
 DensityPlot[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  Frame -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (Opacity[Max[Re[#], 0], 
      GrayLevel[Max[Re[#], 0]]] &), ImageSize -> 40, 
  Background -> Opacity[0, Black]]
```

It is just a semi-transparent gray ball:
[image]
Outside the ball you see white - because of transparency.

**I have a big background**, like this one:

```
InsertIntoImage = Image[GrayLevel[0], ImageSize -> 400];
```

It is just big black background.

**I want to insert the small image into the big one many-many times**, e.g. at these scaled positions:

```
PosList = {Cos[Pi #], Sin[4 Pi #]}^2 & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.005];
```

Vaguely, the result should be like:

```
Rasterize[
  Graphics[{Inset[InsertIntoImage], 
    Inset[InsertImage, Scaled[#]] & /@ PosList}, 
   ImageSize -> 400]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

**Ideally**:

1. I want to add up only grayscale channels of big and small images.
2. Small images are to be added really many times - it is for video production, and the above example is a very light version of it.
3. I want to make it work fast for many more images at a time: Inset is way too slow.

**Question: How to do it with CUDA?**

**Notes on CUDA (why CUDA)**:

1. It should work much faster. Note, the overhead of caching one small image is negligible.
2. I can't seem to find an appropriate inbuilt function: CUDAImageAss[] uses only images of similar size.
3. Putting small images pixel by pixel in matrix form is not very much to my liking. I want to be able to specify small image positions at subpixel accuracy. Normally, this would smear each pixel of each small image with a pointspread function. It is doable, but I believe there must be existing algorithms.
4. Such a problem must have been solved a thousand times, e.g. in videogames, movie production, etc. Note, that GPUs in videogames allow rendering in realtime, hence this approach should work fast here too.

Comment: How quick do you need it? A simple approach using `Part` on packed arrays takes about a tenth of a second.

Comment: @Simon What are you referring to?  How can `Part` be used to inset small images on top of a larger one?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I just mean to work with the image data directly as in `bigarray[[100;;109, 200;;209]] += smallarray` Perhaps I have misunderstood the question?

Comment: @Simon Heh, I guess that would work, wouldn't it? <:o)  Still there must be GPU functions for drawing 2D sprites that should be optimal for this.  Possibly sub-pixel positioning is desired, which is something else to consider.

Comment: I wonder if cuda would be faster than Simon's suggestion given that most of the time must be spent copying to GPU memory, I doubt it. Ahh, I need to get cuda working on linux

Comment: I would be surprised when a CUDA function for this problem is faster than a normal Mathematica function. Copying both images to CUDA memory and copying the result back, only for setting pixel values? This sounds like a bad plan and too much overhead, especially since setting an array like Simon showed should be a vectorized operation anyway.

Comment: @SimonWoods, I have looked at it, but as Mr.Wizard points out, the images get to look rather ugly: because of the absence of antialiasing and subpixel effects. You can check it by making circles out of small dots, for example.

Comment: @Rojo, I should have pointed out, my bad, that the small images (the sprites) are repetitive. That is, among 10000 different sprites only, say, 100 would be unique. I actually plan to use it for animation, so the memory time overhead is not expected to be too large.

Comment: @halirutan, normal mathematica inset works almost painfully slow for this problem. However, say, video games involving sprites and GPUs can render in real time. I suppose, that is quite an argument for CUDA being useful here.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick I don't speak about `Inset`, I speak about setting array elements explicitly in a vectorized way like Simon suggested. Let me make my point clear, for this specific problem where we want to set a 10x10 region in a 1000x1000 image, we have the following to do when using high-level Mathematica: The 1000^2 image is already in main-memory, because, well, we already have it in Mathematica, and Mathematica can access his own memory. Therefore, setting a 10^2 region is similar to 100 write accesses. Compare this to the CUDA approach: First, you have to transfer both images to your..

Comment: .. CUDA device. For this, you have to allocate 1000^2 and 10^2 pixel in the device memory. Then you have to write access each of these pixel while you copy the image. This alone makes 1000100 of the write accesses (you have to read those locations from main memory too). Then you set those 10^2 region in your CUDA device and after this, you copy (again read access in the CUDA and allocation and write access in main memory) those 1000^2 back to main memory. Surely, using `memcpy` will be faster by magnitudes, but nevertheless work is tremendous compared to simply setting 100 memory locations.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick About your clarification point (2): By *doesn't look as good*, do you mean the result? If you speak of *Image Add* like your caption suggests, then I am thinking about a real *image processing image add* where there is no such thing as antialiasing. You do direct pixel-by-pixel operations without adjusting something else. Can you give a specific example about what you mean? Btw, do you know the difference between an *image add* and *setting an image region* which is what `Inset` does?

Comment: @halirutan: On memory accesses, the case is a bit different. As mentioned, I add small images really many times. They can be assumed identical for simplicity. They can overlap etc. 10000x10x10 is the number of accesses needed to put all the images.

Comment: @halirutan: Yes, I understand, what you mean. I would like to be able to set images at a scaled position, e.g. lower left pixel of small image 1 being at (0.55556,0.070901) scaled position of the big image, etc. Overlaying images pixel to pixel does not look identical to what inset does.

Comment: I'm finding the question confusing. A small example would help.

Comment: @SimonWoods: Updated the question! Please, let me know, if it is yet confusing.

Comment: The question is much clearer now, thank you. Note that your `InsertImage` is not actually an image but a `Graphics` expression. Instead of `Inset` you could use `Translate` which is quite efficient at positioning multiple copies of a single object, e.g. `Graphics[Translate[InsertImage[[1]], 20 PosList], Background -> Black]`

Answer (score 12):

Here's how you might approach your problem using direct manipulation of pixel data. First create your graphics:

```
InsertImage = DensityPlot[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> (Opacity[Max[Re[#], 0], GrayLevel[Max[Re[#], 0]]] &), 
  ImageSize -> 20, Background -> Opacity[0, Black]]
```

Now rasterize and extract the graylevel and alpha channels as arrays of real pixel values:

```
{b, a} = ImageData /@ ColorSeparate[InsertImage][[{-2, -1}]];
b = a b; a = 1 - a;
```

The second line is just pre-processing the data for alpha compositing.

Now create the list of positions and the base image:

```
PosList = 1 + Round[980 Rescale[
      Table[Sqrt[t] {Cos[2.4 t], Sin[2.4 t]}, {t, 0., 10000}]]];

base = ConstantArray[0.0, {1000, 1000}];
```

Since speed is important I have put the hard work into a compiled function (it is about 3 times slower in the main evaluator)

```
assemble = 
 Compile[{{base, _Real, 2}, {a, _Real, 2}, {b, _Real, 2}, {PosList, _Integer, 2}},
  Block[{x, y, bs = base},
    Do[{y, x} = p;
     bs[[x ;; x + 19, y ;; y + 19]] = a bs[[x ;; x + 19, y ;; y + 19]] + b,
    {p, PosList}];  bs], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Now run the code:

```
AbsoluteTiming[test = assemble[base, a, b, PosList];]
(*  {0.040002, Null} *)

Image[test]  (* real thing is 1000x1000, smaller version shown below *)
```

[image]

That's 10,000 insertions of a 20x20 image in under 1/20th of a second.

Answer (score 11):

Just for the sake of the argument: Your approach needs about 3.2 seconds for 200 insertions on my machine. Consider this

```
{alpha, col} = Transpose[
   Table[{Boole[Im[#] == 0], Max[Re[#], 0]} &@Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], 
    {x, -1, 1, 2/33.}, {y, -1, 1, 2/33.}], {2, 3, 1}];
inset = SetAlphaChannel[Image[col], Image[alpha]];
spiral = Table[{256, 256} + t*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 300}];
bg = Image[ConstantArray[0, {512, 512}]];
```

Here we have about 300 positions and an inset image with a real alpha-channel like you wanted. Now

```
Fold[ImageCompose[#1, inset, #2] &, bg, spiral] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

takes about 0.2 seconds here. This is almost 15 times faster for 50% more insertions. Would that be fast enough for your problem?